# How to insert bullet character in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a Ruby 1.9.3 string with a bullet character in it.

```
str = "•" + " hello world"
```

But, when I type it in, I get a syntax error about a non-ASCII character.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the Unicode character in there.

```
str = "\u2022" + " hello world"
```

Comment: Tested this in IRB on 1.9.3 and it doesn't work, it just returns the string literal `"\u2022"`. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (ruby 1.9.3)

```
str = "•" + " hello world" 
str # => "• hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ASCII string–but you don't state what version of Ruby you're using. You can also use the Unicode character, `"\u2022"`, if you're using 1.8, or see other options in the primer below.

In 1.9 this should work fine as-is. You can also force UTF-8 using `encode` and/or `force_encoding`.

[Ruby 1.9 Encodings Primer](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/).